# Timeline editing with ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I'm trying to draw a box on one part of the screen at a specific instance in time. I've tried looking through the documentation for ffmpeg-python, but am unable to locate any instance of support for the `enable` option.

I tried using

```py
(
ffmpeg
  .input(video)
  .drawbox(x, y, w, h, enable=f"between(t,{timestamp},{total_time})")
  .output("out.mp4")
  .run()
)
```

hoping that it would be passed to ffmpeg as a kwarg, but this has no effect on the video and the box never gets drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the ffmpeg-python [drawbox documentation](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/#ffmpeg.drawbox) the syntax is:

`ffmpeg.drawbox(stream, x, y, width, height, color, thickness=None, **kwargs)`

The first argument is a stream - it should be a video stream.
We may use `drawbox` filter as follows:

```
filtered_input_video = ffmpeg.drawbox(ffmpeg.input("in.mp4").video, x, y, w, h, color="black", enable=f"between(t, {start_time}, {end_time})")
```

Note that the arguments of `between` are start time and end time.

`filtered_input_video` comes as first argument of `ffmpeg.output`:

```
ffmpeg.output(filtered_input_video, "out.mp4").run()
```

---

Updated code sample (using test pattern as input):

```
import ffmpeg

x, y, w, h = 50, 5, 100, 100
start_time = 3
end_time = 7

input_video = ffmpeg.input("testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10", f="lavfi").video  # Replace this with: ffmpeg.input(video).video

#filtered_input_video = ffmpeg.filter(input_video, "drawbox", x, y, w, h, enable=f"between(t, {start_time}, {end_time})") # Alternative syntax
filtered_input_video = ffmpeg.drawbox(input_video, x, y, w, h, color="black", enable=f"between(t, {start_time}, {end_time})")

(
ffmpeg
  .output(filtered_input_video, "out.mp4", vcodec="libx264", pix_fmt="yuv420p")
  .overwrite_output()  # Overwrite output if already exist (optional)
  .run()
)
```

---

Sample output (box is shown from the 3'rd second to the 7'th):

After 1 second:
[image]

After 5 seconds:
[image]